# Copy the vaules to datagridview to another table with additional info vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am using vb.net and msaccess so I have a database with two tables the 'subject list' and 'student load'.

In 'Student load' I have the columns ID Number, StudentName, SubjectCode, SubjectDescription, Unit, Year, Course, Semester and SchoolYear.

Then in my 'subject list' I have the columns SubjectCode, Subject Description,Unit Year, Course and Semester.

the DGV is filtered by course, year and semester
[image: Subject List DataGridView]

In the picture the dgv is the subject list.
My problem how to insert datas in the studentload table with this things.

I want all in the dgv will be insert to student load plus with the information above like this

[image: Student Load Table]

I dont know how to do it. I am new with this. I hope you help me :)

Comment: Usually be done with a SQL JOIN

Comment: I dont have idea about that. Can you give me example? sorry for the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Use Append Method to transfer datas to another table